# Ion-slide style width is set automatically

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I recently updated my Ionic 2 project to Ionic 3, and the changes to ion-slides have broken my app.

Specific widths are being set in the style tags on the slides when the app loads, and it's breaking my styles.

This is what I have in my HTML:

```
<ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of offer.Gallery">
    <img [src]="image.Url"/>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And this is how it renders:

```
<ion-slides pager="" class="slides slides-md slides-43" ng-reflect-pager="">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal"><div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <ion-slide class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" style="width: 171px;">
            <div class="slide-zoom">
                <img src="IMG">
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </div>
    ... Pagination ...
</ion-slides>
```

You'll notice that somehow the ion-slide tag has a `style="width: 171px;"` set on it. What is causing this and is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Please open in firefox or chrome and right click on the slider.  then please write the class name u see.

Comment: @Dr.Geek The html from chrome is listed in the question, can you be more specific about what else you'd like to see?

Comment: The `style="width: 171px;"` was caculated base on ion-slide**s** width. So to change it just set style for ion-slide**s** element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is not the `width` you need then just change it as shown below.

**Note:** There are No `Saas` variables for this

*your-page.scss*

```
  .md,
  .ios,
  .wp {
      .swiper-slide .swiper-slide-active{
         width: 100px;//your width here
     }
   }
```

**Note:** If above was not working then you must use `width: 100px !important;`. No other option where I can think of.

Comment: I think that would work, but I'd rather not go around shotgunning classes with `!important`s. I'd like to see if there's a "correct" way to get what I want, and possibly understand this "feature" in case I need it later.

Comment: The Ionic team didn't give any `Saas` variables for this. That means you don't have any other option here. Sometimes we need to use `!important`. It is not an evil thing like you think.

Comment: You can try above solution too without `!important`

Comment: Your answer with `!important` is the only thing that's worked so far.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 11):

you can address the ion tags directly in Ionic 3!

A more dynamic solution would be using **unset** value for it.

Just try to write in your *yourpage.scss*:

```
ion-slide { 
width: unset !important;
}
```

and it should remove it!

Comment: your answer works! However it modifies the width for every slide in the app :/ Is there any way to apply that to only a particular slider?

Comment: Make sure you didn't wrote that in you app.scss! Because that's for the whole app! Apply that in your page like home.scss. Second, if you just want pne specific slide, them add an id or class to the slide and call the same code for that :)

Comment: The problem is that wherever I put this style (on app.scss or anywhere) it modifies all the sliders in the app :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ion-slide >:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [slidesPerView option](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/) defaults to 1; to show more slides at a time, increase this in your slider options.

HTML:

```
<ion-slides pager [options]="slideOpts">...
```

typescript:

```
slideOpts:any = {slidesPerView: 7}
```